# How to search for an exact word in a column using Excel filter "Contains"?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am searching for cells that have the word **aldi** in the filter dropdown. So I choose "Contains" and enter **aldi**.

This is bringing back cells that contain Ger**aldi**ne etc.

I've had some success using `aldi *` with the space and asterisk, which removes results like Ger**aldi**ne. But still contains results like **Vivaldi**.

I don't mind if the string contains another word along with **aldi**, e.g. **Aldi shop 123**. I just want to make sure the instance of **aldi** is is by itself.

Sample of data:

```
GERALDINE
RISTORANTE GARIBALDI
ALDI
PORTA GARIBALDI
GRIMALDI
ALDI STORES
```

[image: Screenshot is what I have done so far.]

Comment: Is Aldi always the first word in the desired cells?

Comment: Not always. It could say "New York Aldi".  There are at least 100 different store names that I need to standardize. For example once I clean up Aldi, I will try to standardize all KFC. So I will have to search for all instances of KFC stores e.g. "New York KFC" or "1235 KFC Toronto" or "KFC NY" ... but omit "UKFC Football Club" for example. I need KFC / Aldi etc. to be on their own in the string.

Comment: What if it was always the first word? Use "beings with" ?

Comment: should be `* aldi *`, asterik before and after (with spaces too). But it would be a problem if the cells ends with ` aldi` with no space...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First enter the following User Defined Function in a standard module:

```
Public Function aldi(sIn As String) As String
    arr = Split(LCase(Replace(sIn, ".", "")))
    aldi = "h"
    For Each a In arr
        If a = "aldi" Then
            aldi = "s"
        End If
    Next a
End Function
```

It will return either *"s"* for "show" or *"h"* for "hide"

If your data is in column **A**, then in **B2** enter:

```
=aldi(A2)
```

and copy downward:

[image]

Then filter column **B** to display only the *"s"* rows:

[image]

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to **install** and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To **remove** the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To **use** the UDF from Excel:

```
=aldi(A1)
```

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

**EDIT#1:**

The code line:

```
arr = Split(LCase(Replace(sIn, ".", "")))
```

- takes the phrase or sentence and converts it to lower case; so *Aldi* and *aldi* are treated the same.
- it removes periods so any *aldi.* are considered *"show"*
- it creates an array of words using the space character as the separator.
- it seaches for *"aldi"* in that array

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. What exactly are you doing here? `arr = Split(LCase(Replace(sIn, ".", "")))`

Comment: @SCool  See my **EDIT#1**